# How to save customized interface of DeadBeef?

Tags: interface, defaults, deadbeef

DeadBeeF has a new option, 'Designer mode' allowing to modify the displayed features, modules, addons, in the way Foobar2000 is doing by its layout editing mode.

[image: View menu]

[image: Context menu - Replace With]

---

Example of difficulty:

All the interface can be modified, you may end up with no interface at all or you may find it hard to restore the default one.

After removing the upper area of the default layout, it took me some time to put it back and make it look like so:

[image]

If that is missing you have to put a HBox in all that area, and then, from left to right, in the three boxes: playback controls, seekbar and volume bar. Then, to make it look as before, right-clicking on each of those: check 'fill' for controls (uncheck all the rest), 'expand' and 'fill' for seekbar, uncheck all for volume bar.

[image]

---

Being so new, it is very easy to make mistakes; saving the default or the custom layout would be good. Is there a configuration file that I can backup so that I can save and restore the changes or the default settings?

I see no reset button for the interface changes neither. Is there one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try going to `/home/$USER/.config/` and remove the whole deadbeef config folder to reset. Save that file to backup configuration.

Comment: you mean 'remove' in case i want to reset, and backup the same folder if i want to keep the present configuration?

Comment: yes, remove to reset to default.

Answer (score 1):

To reset the ui, you can also delete the line starting with "gtkui.layout" in the `$HOME/.config/deadbeef/config` file.